# How to configure REST service method with NULL RequestDTO in ServiceStack

Tags: web-services, c#-4.0, servicestack

I am trying ServiceStack to develop few web services, but I am unable to configure method having null as input.

```
public class UserService : IService
{
   public object Get()
   {
       //gets all users 
       //not working
   }
  public object Get(FindUser request)
  {
       //this works
  }
}

public override void Configure(Container container)
{ 
    Routes
   .Add<FindUser>("/user/{id}") //this works
   .Add(null, "/user");//how to configure this route
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no concept of a `null` input, a client must call a specific Service and each Service in [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) needs a request DTO which defines the service entry point and the Request that it receives - that Request DTO can be empty.